# portrait pages following the vertical page numbering on landscape pages

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, page-numbers, footers, landscape

I have several landscape pages on my portrait *Ms. Word 2010* document, and I want to change the ***page number on landscape pages to vertical position.***

What I have done so far:

- section breaks for the landscape pages
- uncheck "link to previous section"
- uncheck "different first page"

But everytime I tried to create the vertical page number (header & footer > page number > page margin), the **vertical number is also shown on the portrait pages**, even though I'm sure I did the section breaks right.

Please help, I am so desperate to get this done!

Answer (score 0):

Please see my lengthy answer in this thread: [Formatting headers and footers in landscape pages to have a portrait orientation](https://superuser.com/questions/1632554/formatting-word-header-and-footer-for-landscape-sections-so-that-they-are-readab/1632622#1632622).

Note that the procedure for doing this applies to all versions of Word.